# Calculate hypotenuse from height and angle

Tags: c#, geometry

I'm a bit rusty on the math department and I want to calculate the hypotenuse of a right angle triangle given the height (h) and opposite angle (C). 
[image: right angle triangle]
I tried this:

```
 double a = h / Math.Sin(v);
```

The whole code snippet:

```
string line;
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] split = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    long h = Int64.Parse(split[0]);
    long v = Int64.Parse(split[1]);
    double res = h / Math.Sin(v);
    Console.WriteLine(res);
}
```

However this doesnt give me the right answer. For instance if the height is 10000 and the angle C is 89, the hypotenuse should be ~10001 but I get ~11626. I've tried this in javascript and C# but I get the same faulty answer, however my calculator gives the correct answer.
Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: post the code pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angle c must be in Radians not degrees

To get Radians use C * Math.PI/180

Comment: Thank you so much, I had forgot about radians. This fixed my problem

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are facing is that your calculation is being done in radians instead of degrees

In order to fix this issue you must convert from degrees to radians like so

```
double c = v * (Math.PI/180);
double a = h/Math.Sin(c);
```